# Compiling cocos2d-x via build_native.py returns: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to build a cocos2d-x 3.0 (stable) project for Android via the `build_native.py` script but it hangs when a class is using the `std::to_string` (or the `std::stoi`) function. Building the project under Xcode gives no problem at all, it's just the command line compilation that fails.

I am already importing `<string>` in all the classes that make use of those functions, but with no success. I also modified the `Application.mk` file like this:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=0 -std=c++11 -Wno-literal-suffix -fsigned-char
```

adding the `-std=c++11` flag to make sure the project is compiled using the C++11 version.

Is there anything else I should do here?

#### More

Following [this thread](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/40419) I decided to include this:

```
#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_MAC || CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS || CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
string to_string(int t) {
    ostringstream os;
    os << t;
    return os.str();
}
#endif
```

in my headers, since I'm just using `to_string` with integer inputs. It is not a good solution, but works fine ... but then the compiler hangs when it finds the `stoi` function, again.

Comment: You could use `boost::lexical_cast` as a replacement for both

Comment: Is the `boost` library compatible with the Android `arm` devices and with iOS too?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm not familiar with either Android or iOS. But you should be able to find that out pretty easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this piece of code:

```
#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
string to_string(int t) {
  ostringstream os;
  os << t;
  return os.str();
}

int stoi(const string myString) {
  return atoi(myString.c_str());
}
#endif
```

Comment: I use   String::createWithFormat("%d",5)->getCString();  to convert numbers to strings

Answer (score 0):

Try using atoi instead of stoi. Altough atoi returns zero on error, but it works with command line compilation

Comment: The problem here is that the command line compiler cannot find the `to_string` and `stoi` (or even `atoi`, probably) functions, but the project builds correctly and runs under Xcode.

Comment: build_native.py command doesn't hangs for me on atoi but hangs on stoi. This changed did solved my issue earlier.

Comment: Yes, but this does not solve the `to_string` problem.

Comment: Agreed, but you have to write to_string method yourself using shift operator as you have already posted sample code. I found this as only option. if somebody comes with better option it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

you can do int to str conversion process by using sstream library, its some long but it works :

```
#include <sstream>
std::stringstream myStringStream ; 
myStringStream << myInteger;
myString = myStringStream.str();
```